# laravel multiple select statement overwrite each other

Tags: sql, laravel-5, mariadb

this is my current QB.

```
$institutes = count($request->input("selected_institutes"));
$courses = count($request->input("selected_courses"));
$institutes_data = $request->input("selected_institutes");
$courses_data = $request->input("selected_courses");
$search=DB::table('users as u');
if($institutes > 0 && $courses = 0){
    $search=$search->select('u.id','u.first_name','u.profile_picture','inst.full_name')
    ->leftJoin('user_institutes as ins','ins.user_id','=','u.id')
    ->leftJoin('institutes as inst','inst.id','=','ins.institute_id');
}
else if($courses > 0 && $institutes = 0){
    $search=$search->select('u.id','u.first_name','u.profile_picture','crse.full_name')
    ->leftJoin('user_courses as crs','crs.user_id','=','u.id')
    ->leftJoin('courses as crse','crse.id','=','crs.course_id');
}
else if($institutes > 0 && $courses > 0){
    $search=$search->select('u.id','u.first_name','u.profile_picture','inst.full_name','crse.full_name')
    ->leftJoin('user_institutes as ins','ins.user_id','=','u.id')
    ->leftJoin('institutes as inst','inst.id','=','ins.institute_id')
    ->leftJoin('user_courses as crs','crs.user_id','=','u.id')
    ->leftJoin('courses as crse','crse.id','=','crs.course_id');
}
$search=$search->WhereNull('u.deleted_at');
for($i=0;$i<$institutes;$i++){
    $search=$search->orWhere('inst.full_name','=',"`$institutes_data[$i]`");
}
for($i=0;$i<$courses;$i++){
     $search=$search->orWhere('crse.full_name','=',"`$courses_data[$i]`");
}
$search=$search->get();
```

the result is based on the input, given scenario is
$institutes = 2 and $courses = 2,
the select query which i printed out 
which i want it to be fall in 2nd else if is shown as below

```
'select * from `users` as `u` where `u`.`deleted_at` is null or `inst`.`full_name` = ?', array('`institutes 1`') or `inst`.`full_name` = ?', array('`institutes 2`')
```

based on this situation the query i want to perform as below

```
select('u.id','u.first_name','u.profile_picture','inst.full_name','crse.full_name')
leftJoin 'user_institutes as ins' on 'ins.user_id''=''u.id'
leftJoin 'institutes as inst' on 'inst.id''=''ins.institute_id'
leftJoin 'user_courses as crs' on 'crs.user_id''=''u.id'
leftJoin 'courses as crse' on 'crse.id''=''crs.course_id'
where 'u.deleted_at' is null
and ('inst.full_name' = 'institutes 1'
or 'inst.full_name' = 'institutes 2')
and ('crse.full_name' = 'courses 1'
or 'crse.full_name' = 'courses 2'}
```

can anyone guide me to structure my QB with these kind of if else condition and running for loop for the where clause variable input.
(apology on my grammar)

Comment: And what gets overwritten?

Comment: Maybe you should just add another one else if for specific number of $institutes = 2 and $courses = 2.

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo, the select statement get overwritten, but i tried to amend the QB and this is the latest, the output just not as what im looking for

Comment: @Grynets, does the following statements meet the condition ?
    
    else if($institutes > 0 && $courses > 0){
    .....
     }

Comment: What does it mean "select statement get overwritten"?

Comment: @kearn I mean else if($institutes == 2 && $courses == 2). We create special condition for this specific case, and as a result can solve your task. It is an easy way to do this.

Comment: i manage to sort it out it is due to the comparison logic within the if - else statement. thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is You want to make a conditional query, which has query join according to the user input (filter criteria),
I have made the following example how to achieve this in Laravel way, try to re write adjust query according to my example.. note that you can add number of `where` or `orWhere` conditions inside the when closures.

```
    $search = DB::table('users as u')
        ->select(['u.id','u.first_name','u.profile_picture','inst.full_name'])
        ->whereNull('u.deleted_at')
        ->when(($request->has("selected_institutes")) && (!$request->has("selected_courses")) , function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->leftJoin('user_institutes as ins','ins.user_id','=','u.id')
                        ->leftJoin('institutes as inst','inst.id','=','ins.institute_id');

        })

        ->when(($request->has("selected_courses")) && (!$request->has("selected_institutes")), function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->leftJoin('user_courses as crs','crs.user_id','=','u.id')
                ->leftJoin('courses as crse','crse.id','=','crs.course_id');

        })

        ->when($request->has("selected_institutes") && $request->has("selected_courses"), function ($query) use ($request) {
            return $query ->leftJoin('user_institutes as ins','ins.user_id','=','u.id')
                ->leftJoin('institutes as inst','inst.id','=','ins.institute_id')
                ->leftJoin('user_courses as crs','crs.user_id','=','u.id')
                ->leftJoin('courses as crse','crse.id','=','crs.course_id');

        })
        ->get();
```